# Conditionally replacing values based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataframe (~1.7MM rows x 6 columns). A simplified example of the relevant data is:

```
City        Borough

Brooklyn    Brooklyn
Astoria     Queens
Astoria     Unspecified
Ridgewood   Unspecified
Ridgewood   Queens
```

So I'm trying to fill the 'Unspecified' values based on the information from the City column. So for example, the City Ridgewood is in an Unspecified Borough in one instance, but correctly has the Borough listed as Queens elsewhere in the dataset.

I've already explored Panda's fillna, but it doesn't seem to meet my needs. I've also considered the np.where method, but I'm not sure how'd it work in this situation. I'm pretty new to Pandas, but maybe the map/apply function are what I need? This can probably be accomplished a thousand different ways, but looking for something that won't crawl given the size of the data.

EDIT: I was able to create a dictionary which contains the highest occurring "pairs" between cities and boroughs with the following code:

```
specified = data[['Borough','City']][data['Borough']!= 'Unspecified']
paired = specified.Borough.groupby(specified.City).max()
paired = paired.to_dict()
```

The paired dict has the city as the key and the borough as the value. Now the last step is to apply/map it back to the borough column...how do I do that?

Comment: After the replacement, do you want duplicate values for these?  That is, do you want to wind up with two identical rows that say "Astoria"/"Queens"?  Or can you just remove the ones with an unspecified value?

Comment: Yes, duplicates are okay and expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
>>> d
         City      Borough
0   Brooklyn     Brooklyn
1    Astoria       Queens
2    Astoria  Unspecified
3  Ridgewood  Unspecified
4  Ridgewood       Queens
>>> realData = d[d.Borough != "Unspecified"]
>>> realData = pandas.Series(data=realData.Borough.values, index=realData.City)
>>> d['Borough'] = d.City.map(realData)
>>> d
         City   Borough
0   Brooklyn  Brooklyn
1    Astoria    Queens
2    Astoria    Queens
3  Ridgewood    Queens
4  Ridgewood    Queens
```

This assumes that every City has exactly one non-unspecified Borough value.  (If a city has no value but Unspecified, the borough will show up as NA.)

Edit: If you've already created your dict as in your edited post, just use `d['Borough'] = d.City.map(paired['Borough'])` to map each city to the borough from your dict.  `map` is a useful method to know about.  It can map values either with a Pandas series, with a dict, or with a function that returns the mapped value given the key.

Comment: There are cases when when the same city may be paired with different boroughs, for instance the city 'New York' is mapped to the Borough Manhattan in like 97% of occurrences, but how does map handle that situation?

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong: It won't work if a city appears with multiple different boroughs.  But what do you want to happen in that case?  How do you want to choose?

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong: See my edited answer.  You can just use `data.City.map(paired)` to get the new boroughs.

Comment: ugh, it seems like the code specified.Borough.groupby(specified.City).max() did not produce the expected results...trying to figure out how to correct

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong: Yeah, that's really a separate question.  Once you have that dict, however you get it, you can use the method I showed.  But you need to clearly define how to choose.  Like what if one city is mapped to two boroughs equally often?

Comment: I just successully mapped the cities/boroughs with one slight modification; when you use the to_dict method, pandas puts the index name as the top level key, with everything else nested, so I had to use d['Borough'] = d.City.map(paired['Borough']. As soon as you can update your answer, I'll give you credit!

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong: Okay, I made that change.